# Does R Shiny have the ability to start playing audio from a certain time stamp?

Tags: javascript, r, audio, shiny

I'm building a Shiny app where users will be able to play snippets of an audio file. The time stamps are from a JSON file to mark each sentence in the audio file. To play the audio I was originally using runjs() like so:

in my input function:

```
tags$audio(id = "audio", controls = NA, autoplay = NA, src = "")
```

and in the server function:

```
observeEvent(input$select.file, {
        runjs(sprintf("document.getElementById('audio').src = '%s';", input$select.file))
      })
```

but I think this will not work for playing a certain segment of the audio. I have been looking at RStudio resources like [this one](https://community.rstudio.com/t/playing-audio-files-in-shiny-r/77296) on playing audio, but I haven't found anything showing how to play a section of the audio that doesn't necessarily start at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp) should work to skip e.g. the first 30 seconds:

```
observeEvent(input$select.file, {
  runjs(sprintf("var myaudio = document.getElementById('audio');
                     myaudio.src = '%s';
                     myaudio.currentTime = 30;", input$select.file))
})
```